# R dendrogram by cluster

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am using R to plot a dendrogram of a hierarchial clustering.

I have realised a hierarchical clustering of ~3000 elements. The plot of the corresponding tree is obviously super messy. These 3000 elements are clustered in 20 groups using the cutree function. What I want is to plot the tree by cluster (i.e. truncated at the nodes where each cluster originate labeled appropriately by cluster => a tree with 20 terminal leaves).

Thanks

O.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reduce `ylim` to the corresponding height:

With random data:

```
set.seed(123)
testdata <- matrix(rnorm(300), ncol=3)
testcah <- hclust(dist(testdata))
```

The height for each step of the cah are in `testdata$heights` from first to last merge. If, for example, you want 5 groups, you need to know the 4th before last height:

```
floor_y <- rev(testcah$height)[5-1]
```

Then, making your object as a dendrogram, you can plot it only on the part you need:

```
testdend <- as.dendrogram(testcah)
plot(testdend, ylim=c(floor_y, attributes(testdend)$height))
```

If you want to label the branches with the clusters' labels, as defined by `cutree`, you need to get the labels (by reordering `cutree` result) and find where to put them along the `x axis`. This information can be obtained by "decomposing" the dendrogram to fin the needed `midpoints`.

First, get the labels of (all) the leaves:

```
testlab <- cutree(testcah, 5)[testcah$order]
```

Then we use a recursive function to find the midpoints of the subdendrograms that lies at the desired height:

```
find_x <- function(dendro, ordrecah, cutheight){
            if(!is.null(attributes(dendro)$leaf)) { # if the dendrogram is a leaf, just get its position in the global dendrogram
                return(which(ordrecah==attributes(dendro)$label))
            } else {
                if(attributes(dendro)$height<cutheight){ # if we're under the height threshold, get the midpoint
                    return(attributes(dendro)$midpoint)
                } else { # if we're above the height threshold, pass the function on the 2 subparts of the dendrogram
                    return(c(find_x(dendro[[1]], ordrecah, cutheight), find_x(dendro[[2]], ordrecah, cutheight)))
                }
            }
           }
```

So we can get the midpoints or leaf position with:

```
test_x <- find_x(testdend, testcah$order, floor_y)
```

but the midpoints correspond to the distance between the leftmost leaf and the node, so, in case of a cluster with more than one member, we need to add the distance from 1 to the leftmostleaf.

```
length_clus <- rle(testlab)$lengths # get the number of members by cluster
test_x[length_clus > 1] <- (test_x + head(c(1, cumsum(length_clus)+1), -1))[length_clus > 1]
```

Finally, put the labels on the plot:

```
mtext(side=1, at=test_x, line=0, text=unique(testlab))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cath. But then how would you tell which cluster is which compared to the cutree function? How would you label on the plot?

Comment: @Oselm please see the edit to place the clusters labels